# How to simultaneously specialize a generic and test for optional as a single line?

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

Is there a way to specialize the generic and test for the optional in one line? In others words, have line #1 and #2 I-as a single line of code?

```
func getTo<T>() -> T? {

    // Real code here replaced by setting nil for clarity
    nil
}



// Working version


// Line #1
let _r: [Any]? = getTo()

// Line #2
if let r = _r { 

    for e in r {
        print ("\(e)")
    }

}

// Not working single line version

// Single line
if let r: [Any]? = getTo() {

    // Error here: error: for-in loop requires '[Any]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?
    //for e in r {
    //         ^

    for e in r {
        print ("\(e)")
    }
}
```

PS: Sorry, initial code was truncated.

Comment: Did you make a mistake in the question? As far as I see, you can just inline `_r`: `guard let r = getTo(breadcrumbs: ["here"]) else { return nil }`

Comment: Ooops, sorry, you're right. My code was truncated. I just edited the question.

Comment: Lol your original question has absolutely nothing to do with the edited one. I think you're just looking for `guard let r: [Any] = getTo(breadcrumbs: ["error"]) else { return }`. But generally generic functions whose generic types are only used in the return line are a bit clunky, for exactly this reason. If you look at built-in APIs, like `unsafeBitCast(_:to:)`, you'll notice that they take an unused arg of `T.Type`, for the sole purpose of defining what the value of the generic arg should be.

Comment: Sorry about that. The idea version was missing. (I tried to streamline a low-counting line numbers from an actual app code. And here it's late. Again sorry about that.

Comment: That's okay :p Coudl you take a second to refine this so all the irrelevant parts are removed? e.g. the `r` in `getTo` is unneeded, nor is the `breadcrumbs` param.

Comment: To give you more insight, the getTo function is used to access to a specific node of a json structure whose type can be anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213286/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-stephane-de-luca).

Comment: Just remove the `?` after the `[Any]` in the `guard let`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This works:

```
guard let r: [Any] = getTo(breadcrumbs: ["here"]) else {
    return nil
}
```